# Cant deserialize inherited object with Mongo c# driver

Tags: c#, mongodb, asp.net-core, mongodb-.net-driver

I am using [`AspNetCore.Identity.MongoDB` nuget package](https://github.com/tugberkugurlu/AspNetCore.Identity.MongoDB) to get some Asp.Net Identity features into [my project](https://github.com/Mech0z/FoosballCore2/Identity).

Then I want to extend the `MongoIdentityUser` that exists with the User type I originally created for my project, so I tried to inherit from that class and create [my User Class](https://github.com/Mech0z/FoosballCore2/blob/Identity/src/Models/User.cs) that has `MongoIdentityUser` as its base class.

If I try to query my collection where I have one `MongoIdentityUser` stored and try to deserialize it into `MongoIdentityUser` I get that one item out, so success.

But if I try to deserialize it into [My User](https://github.com/Mech0z/FoosballCore2/blob/Identity/src/Models/User.cs) which is just an inherited class of `MongoDBUser` I get this exception:
[image: Exception]

Is it not possible to extent a class like that I want? Also the exception is pretty useless, not sure why its not giving me a more detailed exception

The json object looks like this

```
{
    "_id": "dat@email.com",
    "userName": "dat@email.com",
    "normalizedUserName": "dat@email.com",
    "email": {
        "value": "dat@email.com",
        "confirmationRecord": null,
        "normalizedValue": "dat@email.com"
    },
    "phoneNumber": null,
    "passwordHash": "xxx",
    "securityStamp": "87242bb7-2a09-4905-ba61",
    "isTwoFactorEnabled": false,
    "claims": [],
    "logins": [],
    "accessFailedCount": 0,
    "isLockoutEnabled": true,
    "lockoutEndDate": null,
    "createdOn": {
        "instant": {
            "$date": "2016-11-13T17:05:59.487Z"
        }
    },
    "deletedOn": null
}
```

Comment: IMHO, you forgot to register your derived class by using something like `BsonClassMap.LookupClassMap(typeof(User))` ;).

Comment: @shA.t but wont that only give me only either MongoIdentityUser properties or Users properties and not both classes properties?

Comment: This is not about properties this is about classes that MongoDB can serialize based on them read [this for more](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.0/reference/bson/mapping/) ;).

Comment: Dit not help, also normally I would get a mapping error, but this nullreference exception in the driver seems wrong

Comment: The exception said that result of deserializing is null and you can't call `.ToList()` method for a null object, Bson serializer needs to know all your classes ;).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed in the latest release of the framework https://github.com/tugberkugurlu/AspNetCore.Identity.MongoDB/releases/tag/1.0.0-rc3